# javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-websocket

I am facing a problem while deploying a war on to tomcat instance,

Tomcat version details,

```
D:\Kiran\Kiran\Softwares DH\Webservers\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\bin>version.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\Kiran\Kiran\Softwares DH\Webservers\apache-tomcat-7.0.63"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\Kiran\Kiran\Softwares DH\Webservers\apache-tomcat-7.0.63"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\Kiran\Kiran\Softwares DH\Webservers\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\Kiran\Kiran\Softwares DH\Webservers\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\Kiran\Kiran\Softwares DH\Webservers\apache-to
mcat-7.0.63\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.63
Server built:   Jun 30 2015 08:08:33 UTC
Server number:  7.0.63.0
OS Name:        Windows 7
OS Version:     6.1
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_07-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
D:\Kiran\Kiran\Softwares DH\Webservers\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\bin>
```

POM Dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have created a war using maven plugin and tried to deploy on tomcat 7. I was able to deploy but unable to start the webapp. When I find the logs for it, it gave below stacktrace,

```
SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5520)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:694)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

---

**Edit :**

It runs fine when I run the application using STS

Comment: Does Tomcat 7 have JSR-356 support?

Comment: According to this [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html). Yes tomcat 7 has JSR 356 support

Comment: @Kayaman Please check the answer. I have updated it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is identified to be confusion over the websocket jars of tomcat and my application jars. I have removed it from the war file and it started working,

I used maven plug in to remove the jars as below,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The jars which were creating problem are,

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Search in pom.xml for

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and remove it.

Comment: @kryger - I have removed the spring-boot-starter-jetty from my dependency, but still its not working and below are my tomcat details
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.33
Server built:   Mar 11 2020 09:31:38 UTC
Server number:  9.0.33.0
OS Name:        Windows 10
OS Version:     10.0
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_151-b12
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by Kiran in another answer, the problematic libraries are websocket-*.jar(s). I encountered these dependencies to be introduced by (upgrade of) Active MQ library in a project.
So in case you have the same error, look for the maven dependency tree in your project and exclude the dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=javax.websocket
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding a WEB-INF/web.xml file with the following contents. We need to configure Tomcat to ignore Jetty SCI(ServerContainerInitializer) implementations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <absolute-ordering>
    <name>spring_web</name>
  </absolute-ordering>

</web-app>
```

There are some explanation on this:

- [ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/tomcat)
- [[AMQ-6154] ActiveMQ with websocket on Tomcat fails with NullPointerException at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6154?focusedCommentId=15130390&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-15130390)
- [HowTo FasterStartUp - Apache Tomcat - Apache Software Foundation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp#HowToFasterStartUp-Configureyourwebapplication)