# Unable Deploy Spring on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Today I got an error like that one below, when I compiled a Spring project on Eclipse. I did not change any windows variable or environment variable on eclipse.

```
...
May 18, 2016 4:56:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

May 18, 2016 4:56:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/api] startup failed due to previous errors
May 18, 2016 4:56:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 18, 2016 4:56:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 18, 2016 4:56:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4673 ms
```

Please help me...
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202344/javax-servlet-servletexception-not-running-on-jetty-jsr-356-support-unavailabl

Comment: thanks.. this solution working perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32717377/5478096