# Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing on Tomcat 9 with Vaadin 14 Application - Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat9, vaadin-flow

I try to run a Vaadin 14, Spring-Boot, Java 8 Application on a Tomcat 9.
The maven-build looks good, but when I deploy the war on the Tomcat, I get an error.

I already tried this:
[javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202344/javax-servlet-servletexception-not-running-on-jetty-jsr-356-support-unavailabl)
But I dont have a "spring-boot-starter-jetty"-dependency in my pom.
And excluding jars with "WEB-INF/lib/websocket-*.jar" did not help.

Any help or idea would be appreciated. Thank you.

I am not using Jetty, why the Application thinks it is/has to run on Jetty? "Not running on Jetty"?

The Tomcat Log:

```
13-Sep-2019 22:23:34.491 SCHWERWIEGEND [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5120)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1621)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1351)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1355)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1333)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.fss.paul</groupId>
<artifactId>paul</artifactId>
<name>paul</name>
<version>1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>

    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <vaadin.version>14.0.1</vaadin.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.0.0.M7</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>webjars</id>
            <url>https://dl.bintray.com/webjars/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version> -->
    </parent>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql Connector Treiber -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Test1 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>production</id>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Test1 -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>productionMode</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>vaadin.productionMode</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Test1 -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/websocket*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <jvmArguments>-Dvaadin.productionMode</jvmArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you checked this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202344/javax-servlet-servletexception-not-running-on-jetty-jsr-356-support-unavailabl ?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Didn't  help.